# How are numbers greater than 9 written in ASCII?

Tags: encoding, binary, encode

I have looked into the ASCII system and a pattern I saw was their use of 1's to denote the type of character being represented. For example in typical binary 00000001 will just represent 1 while in ASII 00110001 represents 1. This same thing caries over to the letters with 01100001 representing the letter a. Now my question is how are numbers greater than 9 represented in this system? From my basic understanding the way old computers got around low bit systems was by combining the numbers in memory but if this is done how is it represented?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [cs.se]

Comment: With two or more bytes. ASCII encodes text. The byte is not a number, it is a placeholder. Each byte is an index into a lookup table that associates a number with a symbol. This lookup table is what the ASCII encoding defines.

Comment: When i write out "10", that is two characters, a '1' and a '0'. If you're using hexadecimal representation, 'A' could be 10 in decimal up to 15 being 'F'.